# Where did the menu bar clock go?

Tags: indicator

I like having a clock showing the current time and date in the menu bar, but this morning when I logged in it's not there anymore. Everything under System Settings > Time & Date > Clock is greyed out. Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1228360) has already been reported.

a quick fix (in terminal):

> killall unity-panel-service

Comment: I had to run the command in _sudo_ mode to make it work (as said in the comments of the bug). If it does not work _without sudo_ for you, `sudo killall unity-panel-service`.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS just presented the same issue.

Comment: Can confirm - 14.04 regression

Comment: Just happened to me on Ubuntu 14.04.2 (kernel v 3.16.0-41-generic). The System setting panel for datetime is fully functional but the darn thing does not appear on the Unity bar. Also the above fix did not work. Nor does `> dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata`......  `> sudo restart lightdm` rebooted the system with nochange after reboot.

Comment: It might happen after you [install the f.lux indicator](https://gist.github.com/robertboloc/9feaa9150926efa4175a).

Comment: 16.04. still reproducible. the killall unity-panel-service did not help